# Python timer not working in real time

Tags: python, timer

I am writing a countdown in python but it doesn't work.

```
for countdown in 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, quit():
    print (countdown)
```

That's the code. The countdown just zooms by and quits the program. Is there a way to make the countdown comply to real time and countdown and quit in 10 seconds. Not immediately.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print

Comment: Maybe I'm just stupid, but I don't see any timer at all. Just a regular full-speed-ahead for loop.

Comment: @Pythonist, what led you to believe that some kind of delay would occur? Or are you just asking us to create a timer for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell it to wait otherwise it will run the code as fast as your processor can do it.

```
from time import sleep
for countdown in range(10,0,-1):
  print(countdown)
  sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr python buffers print, and python isn't *that* slow

```
import sys, time
for countdown in range(10,1,-1):
    print(countdown)
    sys.stdout.flush() #flushes buffer
    time.sleep(1) #sleep for one second, otherwise loop goes very quickly
print(0)
sys.stdout.flush()
# no quit needed. Program will end when file ends
```

Comment: Why are you iterating an iterable containing `quit()` within?

Comment: Uh, my lack of excuse is "I didn't realize that was a builtin and thought that it was some random function OP had for garbage collection" :P